# Determine if request came through a Facebook page tab

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-php-sdk

If the user visits foobar.com through a Facebook page tab I'd like to show them specific data.

However, if the user goes directly to foobar.com I'd like to show something different.

I've not been able to come up with one good method to do so.

Comment: unless you control the url they hit IE: www.foobar.com?from=facebook, you can't with 100% certainty, as http is stateless.

Comment: Look at http_referrer about half way down this page http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php although it's not very reliable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check out [signed_request](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/signed_request/) which is sent to each page loaded in a Facebook tab.

```
if (isset($signed_request['page'])) {
   // I'm in a tab  
}
```